how to check that the bot is running in telethon
i tried Redis before it, still not working i want to get informations from bot and send them to web page. i want check the bot its running or not, checking that in another file.
this is my simple code, help me to complete it
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

import cfg

api_id = cfg.API_ID

api_hash = cfg.API_HASH

bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash)

bot.start()





@bot.on(events.NewMessage)

async def my_event_handler(event):

    if 'hello' in event.raw_text:

        await event.reply('hi!')



bot.run_until_disconnected()


what is bot.start()?  Maybe you should run it after at the end.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

The call to run_until_disconnected doesn't return until the bot is disconnected. This means that, if you import the file, the import won't "finish" until the bot is disconnected. You will need to restructure your code a significant amount to achieve what you're asking for.
